# Android studio layout size folders

Tags: android, android-styles, android-screen-support

I'm trying to create a different layout for 1080dp and others using 
"layout-sw1080dp" folder but it seems android studio completely ignores it and loads from the default layout folder.

I've tried another way - setting different dimensions using values-sw1080dp and still nothing!

What is the correct way to write different layouts for different screen sizes?

Comment: From docs : Notice that the previous two sets of example resources use the "smallest width" qualifer, sw<N>dp, which specifies the smallest of the screen's two sides, regardless of the device's current orientation. Thus, using sw<N>dp is a simple way to specify the overall screen size available for your layout by ignoring the screen's orientation.

Comment: I dont understand what u r saying - I am using this qualifiers but it's not working properly

Comment: If you use, sw<N>dp, the smaller of the height / width, should be atleast N dp in size. Since you're using 1080, both your height and width should be atleast 1080dp in length.

Comment: Just FYI : 

ldpi @ 1080.00dp  = 810.00px, 
mdpi @ 1080.00dp  = 1080.00px, 
hdpi @ 1080.00dp  = 1620.00px, 
xhdpi @ 1080.00dp  = 2160.00px

Comment: I'm starting to think it's some kind of a bug in android studio. I'm doing what the android docs are suggesting - using the sw1080dp folder and also checked on a nexus 5 emulator which is 1080p

Comment: it's not a bug on anything. Please read my answer.

Comment: LG G2 is 1080 pixels * 1920 pixels. 1080px in xhdpi means 540dp which is much less than the 1080dp value you're using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**DP is not the same as PIXEL!!!**

You think it's ignoring because devices with 1080dp do not exist (yet?).

- values-sw720dp: that's for Nexus 9 and 10 inch tablets
- values-sw600dp: that's for 7 to 8 inch tablets
- values-sw360dp: that's for small phones

I suggest you installing this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.qbus.sizemeup&hl=en on your devices, it shows the size of each devive in pixels and in DP.

Also, read more about it here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Excellent answer exactly what I needed. Thank you and that app will be of great value.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Android Studio (version > 0.8) groups resources with the same name into one folder, with their distinguishing qualifiers in a muted grey. Be sure you're also using the [correct qualifiers.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you I know it. It's only because you are at the "android" view. change it to project and it will be back to normal

Answer (score 0):

The modifier you're using `sw<N>dp` (smallest width) represents resources for the shortest of the screen's available height and width.

Are you sure your shortest screen's dimension are not less than 1080dp?

Read more about resource folder modifiers [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

Comment: I'm testing on LG G2 and it's a 1080 x 1920 resolution so it should work no? I'll try a lower number just to test

Comment: Resolution is pixels is not the same with `dp` — density independent pixels.  The actual size in `dp` depends on device's density which may be `mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xhdpi` etc.

[More info](http://blog.edwinevans.me/?p=131) about android screen units.