# Android Studio group resources

Tags: android

How can I set Android Studio to group my resources by name and not by size?

I found this: [Android studio layout size folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301472/android-studio-layout-size-folders), but my resources aren't grouped like that (by name), but by size like this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/048qL.jpg)

What I want to achieve:[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VXko.png)

Comment: The "like this" link is not working. Please note that you can embed images directly in the question; this is in any case preferable to external links.

Comment: What do you mean resources? the resources file or the resources forlder/directory? If you want to group or sort your resources file, then just create a proper naming like `a_drawable_one.xml`, `a_drawable_two.xml`, `b_drawable_one.xml`, `b_drawable_two.xml`

Comment: I want to be able to see a resource (drawable, layout, etc) only once in the hierarchy and be able to expand it in order to see it's available sizes (like the picture with the result). 
Right now, a certain resource (main_layout.xml lets say) is under multiple folders (layout-xlarge, layout-land etc). I want to see the layout as a folder so to say, and under it, all it's available versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From top left in Android Studio Change **Android** mode to **Project** mode, like [image: THIS PHOTO].

If you can't see previews photo, Open [THIS LINK](https://ibb.co/dcahiw).

Comment: Actually I already had it set on Project. Seems that changing it to Android fixed it. (maybe for some users is works the opposite way).  Your answer is still useful as I wouldn't have thought to look there. Thanks!

Comment: @MaryA : I couldn't open your photo, so I guessed your purpose. Anyway, you can change mode to reach your purpose.